# Нужна ли запятая перед "что" в данном случае?

Tags: запятые

*Когда думаешь(,) что хочешь спать*

Answer (score 2):

Да, это обычное СПП. Запятая не ставится, только если придаточное состоит из одного слова: *Сам не знаю почему; Он не сказал где* и т. п.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova: зачем прописная? Там же два примера придаточных, а не полное предложение.

Comment: О, Тёмыч, я недопоняла! Тогда оба с прописной (это ж не слово, не словосочетание, а целые предложения), но между ними ставится тэзэ. Исправила.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova: целые придаточные, но не целые полные предложения. Разве в таком случае надо с большой буквы?

Comment: Фу ты, Тёмка, пошто пугаешь немолодую деушку?! Розенталь: ***Не ставится запятая между главным и следующим за ним придаточным предложением: ...в)       если придаточное предложение состоит из одного только союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия), например: Меня упрекают, но не знаю в чем; Уходя, он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил когда; Мать температуру определяла губами: приложит губы ко лбу и сразу определит сколько.*** http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova: ой, да, я неправильно назвал. Про запятую я и так знаю в этом случае. Придаточное действительно состоит только из одного слова, да, но всё равно я хотел сказать, что это неполные предложения (не чисто придаточные, вместе с частью главной части, но всё равно неполные). В случае таких **неполных** правильно их начинать с большой буквы?

Comment: Ну, какое бы ни было предложение, в отличие от словосочетания (хоть назывное из одного слова), в перечне примеров каждое будет с прописной и на точках с запятой.

Answer (score 0):

**Когда думаешь, что хочешь спать.**
Я думаю, что это придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения, в котором главная часть опущена. Обычно такие конструкции встречаются при ответе на вопрос.
Запятая перед союзом "что" ставится по [общим правилам](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html).

Представим себе диалог (кто-то изо всех сил старается не уснуть).

— Когда же мне выпить это лекарство?
— [Выпей его тогда,] *когда* [ты] *думаешь, что хочешь спать.*

Вот обратная ситуация, но запятая перед "что" все равно ставится.

*Возможно, **ты думаешь, что не хочешь спать**, и держишь глаза открытыми. Но чем сильнее ты борешься со сном, тем тяжелее становятся веки. Так и должно быть: твои глазки устают тем больше, чем дольше **ты думаешь, что не хочешь спать**.*
Карл-Йохан Форссен Эрлин. Тракторёнок, который хочет уснуть